# suddenly visual studio xaml lacks "view code" option?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

Has anyone ever seen this before behaviour in VS 2017 before?

```
-------------------------
View Code F7
View Designer Shift+F7
```

this sub menu is simply missing. Once. On one file.

This project has around 400 xaml/xaml.cs files. All work fine. But for some reason visual studio refuses to allow the option that says "view code f7" **on this ONE file**. Despite it being xaml/xaml.cs and despite there being an issue if you click the more icon - it's driving me nuts has anyone ever seen this before? what is the cause how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: a) Create a backup of your project, start deleting everything but this file where the menu is missing and another file for comparison. Inspect the project files to understand what is going an. b) Add a new file, compare it with your broken file, change the new file step by step to replace the broken file, at one point, it might behave like the other. In short, create a test case and strip your problem down.

Comment: ... or I could click more ">" and right click every time.. just want to know the cause `^_^`

Comment: I've seeing this for different type of files. And it usually is fixed by using "Open With..." and selecting "Source Code" *once*. After that the menu option is there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and broke something else in the process

Micha Wiedenmann was right it was in the proj file.

solution:

- close Visual Studio
- open your `\<Project>.csproj` file in an editor NOT visual studio (I used atom)
- scroll to this piece of code

below

```
 ...
 <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
    <Page Include="Views\BAD.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\GOOD.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
```

you will see `<SubType>Designer</SubType>` is missing for the BAD.xaml file. Add it.

voila when you restart VS the right click option is there!

trouble is then you get this error (if you *use* the new menu)

```
   After selecting the "View Designer" menu during a xaml file editing 
   the following message displayed: There is no editor available for the
   "C:\<filepath>app.xaml" Make sure the application for the type (.xaml)
   is installed.
```

which I don't know how to fix. but at least the `view code` option is there, shame you can't use it.